# ReferenceError: "google is not defined"

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps, typescript-typings

I use [Angular Google Maps](https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/) to display a google map in my angular 7 app.

I needed google maps typings to do something like this:

```
allowedBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(51.130739, -0.868052), // SW
    new google.maps.LatLng(51.891257, 0.559417) // NE
);
```

So I did `npm install --save-dev @typings/googlemaps`

I tried many different things to try to resolve the error but none worked for me.

```
import {} from 'googlemaps'
declare const google: any;
```

In tsconfig.json I have `"typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"]` and in tsconfig.app.json `"types": ["googlemaps"]`

The app compiles without errors but in chrome console I get an error:

`ERROR ReferenceError: "google is not defined"`

Comment: If you're able to compile without issue, you don't have a problem with your `@types` configuration. Your browser is saying `google is not defined`. Have you included the scripts that define `google` globally, and are they loaded before this script is executed?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This error most likely occurs since the moment when `allowedBounds`  is getting initialized, Google Maps API is *not yet loaded* and therefore Google Maps objects like `google.maps.LatLngBounds` are not yet available. `agm-map` ships with [loader](https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/injectables/lazymapsapiloader) which loads Google Maps library *asynchronously*.

In order to ensure Google Maps API is loaded, [`MapsAPILoader` service](https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/injectables/mapsapiloader) could be utilized as demonstrated below:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  bounds = null;

  constructor(private mapsAPILoader: MapsAPILoader) {
    this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
      this.bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
        new google.maps.LatLng(51.130739, -0.868052), // SW
        new google.maps.LatLng(51.891257, 0.559417) // NE
      );
      console.log(this.bounds);
    });
  }

}
```

[Here is a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-google-maps-demo-abzw4k) which demonstrates how to fit a map for a given bounds

Comment: looks like `@agm/core` (newest ver as of 24/07/2021) uses the old types present in the deprecated pkg `@types/googlemaps` and not the newer one (`@types/google.maps`). Is there a new reccomended way of embedding g.maps into angular app?

Comment: @DuckLing check this one https://smaillounes.medium.com/integrating-google-maps-in-angular-application-using-angular-google-maps-280a66c32c57